# Javax validation, validate an object's property with annotations

Tags: java, validation, annotations

Let's say I have the following classes :

```
public class MyProductCode  {
    private String code;
    // getter and setter
}

public class MyProduct {
    @NotNull
    private MyProductCode myCode;
    // getter and setter
}
```

Is it possible to validate the "code" property via the "MyProduct" class ?
Something like this :

```
@NotNull(property = "code")
private MyProductCode myCode;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Oval framework, it would be possible:

Refer [Declaring constraints for nested properties](http://oval.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#declaring-nested-property-constraints)

Comment: Hey that's a pretty interesting framework ! Thanks for the link, it seems that's what I'm looking for :)